# Position of axis. Does it work?

Tags: jquery, flot

Im trying simply put yaxis on the right side, so accordingly to Flot Api my code is :

```
$.plot($('#values_plot'),[{
    data: values 
 }],{   
yaxis { position : "right"}
 });
```

As a result yaxis stays on the left side. I suppose that either I made some silly mistake or it is simply not working. Please help !

Comment: The code you have supplied here is not valid JavaScript, and would give you a syntax error in your browser if you look in the error console. Please post exactly what your code looks like, or (preferably) put a pared-down test case showing the actual problem online for us to help with.

Comment: are you missing a `:` after the yaxis word ?

Answer (score 4):

**If you grabbed the latest version of Flot, the documentation is incorrect.  If you want to plot against the right side, change yaxis to yaxis2 in your data object.**

Here is how you would specify the series object:

```
series: [ { label: "Foo", yaxis: 2, data: [ [10, 1], [17, -14], [30, 5] ] } ]
```

I ran into the same problem and had to look at the Flot code to figure it out.

Comment: The latest version (i.e. SVN) is even more complicated - you can have arbitrary numbers of axes... The results are pretty neat though... See "multiple axes" in the dev version: http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt